# MySQL Group by, I want to group by 'shrn_trpr_nm' and Order By

Tags: mysql, group-by

```
SELECT
    ptl_id,chnl_id, shrn_srno, shrn_trpr_nm
FROM schd_shrn_infm
 WHERE 
    ptl_id = 'PTL_51'
AND chnl_id = 'CHNL_1'
AND schd_srno = 100000001480
ORDER BY
   shrn_trpr_nm
LIMIT 10
```

I want grouop by shrn_trpr_nm, what should I do?

Comment: Please remove the javascript tag. And, you have nothing in your from clause. To order by shrn_trpr_nm, you should do exactly what you are doing, maybe order by shrn_trpr_nm desc if you want the reverse order.

Comment: What is your problem? Details missing.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

To also return the other columns, you're going to have to get an aggregated version of them, for example `max()`:

```
SELECT
    max(ptl_id) ptl_id,    -- use max()
    max(chnl_id) chnl_id,
    max(shrn_srno) shrn_srno,
    shrn_trpr_nm
FROM schd_shrn_infm
WHERE ptl_id = 'PTL_51'
AND chnl_id = 'CHNL_1'
AND schd_srno = 100000001480
GROUP BY shrn_trpr_nm    -- add this line
ORDER BY shrn_trpr_nm
LIMIT 10
```

Since the other are columns fixed via the `WHERE` clause, `max()` will be fine.

Answer (score -1):

can't understated where is the problem

just put the field in the order and in the group

```
SELECT
    ptl_id,chnl_id, shrn_srno, shrn_trpr_nm
FROM WHERE 
    ptl_id = 'PTL_51'
AND chnl_id = 'CHNL_1'
AND schd_srno = 100000001480
GROUP BY
     shrn_trpr_nm
ORDER BY
   shrn_trpr_nm
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Whatever the problem is, this ISN'T the answer!